# Calculator Bearing different?

Tags: qgis, bearing

I am trying to calculator the bearing/ heading of each line. The value are different when I use the expression "degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))" to the Measure Bearing tool. Is there a different expression to use?

[image]

Comment: Be careful. If your units are degrees or Web Mercator meters, the angle will be wrong.

Comment: I did some test and the expression give the same bearing that the one used in the Advanced digitizing panel to construct the line (work only with line in projected CRS).  My guess is that the azimuth expression and the bearing tool don't have the same way to calculate bearing, could be grid north for azimuth expression and true north for bearing tool or this is a bug in the bearing tool. I hope somebody could clarify this….

Comment: @Vince I did test with line in projected CRS (both layer and project in
 Lambert Conformal Conic EPSG:2154) and there is still a difference between the expression and the bearing tool...

Comment: A conic projection will show skew away from the central meridian (the further away, the worse it gets). Using geodesic calculation will find the great ellipse bearing (but even that will not agree with a magnetic compass bearing).

Comment: @vince does that mean that the bearing tool give you the "real" bearing (relative to true north) while bearing calculation depend on the projection properties ? (And sure magnetic north is a totally different thing,keep changing all the time)

Comment: Dunno. I trust ArcPy to give the same bearing value as some FORTRAN I ported from the US Geodetic Survey. I haven't played with the QGIS functions.